# Rules for escaping formulas and variables

Tags: excel, vba, escaping, evaluate

I know it's been asked several times, but I just don't get it.
I'd like to know the rules in order to correctly build VBA code which incorporates formulas and variables in a VBA Evaluate function.
This works ok:

```
stringa_per_mesi = "=DATEDIF(""" & d1 & """,""" & WorksheetFunction.EDate(d1, 12) & """,""ym"")"  
mesi = Application.Evaluate(stringa_per_mesi)
```

I have to write a more complex formula with Evaluate but I get lost, so I have to solve the doubts I have.

In the above example, why couldn't I just write

```
stringa_per_mesi = "=DATEDIF(d1, & WorksheetFunction.EDate(d1, 12) & """,""ym"")"
```

and why this works

```
WorksheetFunction.EDate(d1, 12)
```

even without quotation marks here (d1, 12)?

Thank you!

Comment: When you use `Evaluate`, you need to pass it a string which looks exactly the same as you would use in a worksheet formula.  If you're having problem, then using Debug.Print to output the string to the immediate window should help.  Try pasting the string into a worksheet cell and see if it gives you errors.  Using WorksheetFunction is quite a different approach from Evaluate: with WorksheetFunction it's more like working in VBA than using worksheet formula syntax

Comment: Hi Tim, you pointed me in the right direction! Thank you!